# To a find a year in a string using Regular expression in perl

Tags: perl

input.txt

```
Ken, Robert. (1994). Lessons from Hull House for the contemporary urban university 2008. Social Service Review, 68(3), 299-321.

Robert, John. 1994. Lessons from Hull House for the contemporary urban university 2008. Social Service Review.
```

Output.txt

```
Ken, Robert. (<y>1994</y>). Lessons from Hull House for the contemporary urban university 2008. Social Service Review, 68(3), 299-321.

Robert, John. <y>1994</y>. Lessons from Hull House for the contemporary urban university 2008. Social Service Review.
```

I have tried the following coding, but i get the tag  for the last occyears
Can someone fine me the solution

```
print "Enter the exp file name without extension: ";
chomp($filename = <STDIN>);
open(RED, "$filename.txt") || die "Could not open EXP file";
open(WRIT, ">$filename.html");

while(<RED>) {
    if(/(.+)(\d{4})/) {
        s/(.+)(\d{4})/$1<y>$2<\/y>/g;
    }
print WRIT $_;
}
close(RED);
close(WRIT);
```

Comment: Your whole program can be replaced with this: `perl -pe's#(\d{4})#<y>$1</y>#g' input > output`

Comment: I have tried the above coding. It generates <y> tag for all years. But can i know how to tag <y> only for the first occurrence i.e. only for <y>1994</y> and not for 2008

Answer (score 2):

You have greedy regex, so only last year in every line gets matched. `?` makes `+` quantifier non-greedy (don't match as much as possible)

```
if (/(.+?)(\d{4})/) {
   s/(.+?)(\d{4})/$1<y>$2<\/y>/g;
}
```

As a side note, you can simplify above code with

```
s/(\d{4})/<y>$1<\/y>/g;
```

Comment: I have tried the above coding. It generates <y> tag for all years. But can i know how to tag <y> only for the first occurrence i.e. only for <y>1994</y> and not for 2008

Comment: @PLT omit `/g` in regex to only match first year.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to first match a year and then substitute it.

There is no need to capture stuff you aren’t matching.

There is, however, a need to make sure you’re talking about legitimate years — ones that are four digits long and perhaps also within the last or current century.

The shortest way of saying that is certainly a way you never want to use:

```
# DO NOT USE THIS: IT IS ILLEGIBLE!!
s{(\b(?=19|20)\d{4}\b)}{<y>$1</y>}g;
```

Instead, you should break it up so it can be more readily read:

```
s{
    (                   # save in numbered buffer $1
        \b              # word-break
        (?= 19 | 20)    # next two chars must be either 19 or 20
        \d{4}           # the year proper
        \b              # word break
    )                   # end of numbered capture $1
}{<y>$1</y>}gx;
```

If you are running Perl v5.10 or better, you can use named captures not just numbered ones:

```
s{
    (?<YEAR>            # save in named buffer "year"
        \b              # word-break
        (?= 19 | 20)    # next two chars must be either 19 or 20
        \d{4}           # the year proper
        \b              # word break
    )                   # end of named capture "year"
}{<y>$+{YEAR}</y>}gx;
```

If the replacement portion seems too compressed, you can also use this:

```
s{
    (?<YEAR>            # save in named buffer "year"
        \b              # word-break
        (?= 19 | 20)    # next two chars must be either 19 or 20
        \d{4}           # the year proper
        \b              # word break
    )                   # end of named capture "year"
}{
    "<y>"       .
    $+{YEAR}    .
    "</y>"
}egx;
```

Finally, you should be aware that `\d` matches any code point with the `Numeric_Type=Decimal` character property, not ASCII only. Therefore, to avoid false positives you may wish to exchange `\d` for `[0-9]`:

```
s{
    (?<YEAR>            # save in named buffer "year"
        \b              # word-break
        (?= 19 | 20)    # next two chars must be either 19 or 20
        [0-9]{4}        # the year proper
        \b              # word break
    )                   # end of named capture "year"
}{
    "<y>"       .
    $+{YEAR}    .
    "</y>"
}egx;
```

Alternately, if you are running Perl v5.14 or better, you can use the `/a` option:

```
s{
    (?<YEAR>            # save in named buffer "year"
        \b              # word-break
        (?= 19 | 20)    # next two chars must be either 19 or 20
        \d{4}           # the year proper
        \b              # word break
    )                   # end of named capture "year"
}{
    "<y>"       .
    $+{YEAR}    .
    "</y>"
}egxa;
```

If you decide that other centuries are applicable, it is easy to modify the lookahead that restricts which centuries are permitted.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're getting tripped up by is regular expression matching is greedy. That means that: `.+` is grabbing everything that it can, leaving only just enough to fulfill the second match.

So it'll only work once on:

```
Ken, Robert. (1994). Lessons from Hull House for the contemporary urban university 2008. Social Service Review, 68(3), 299-321.
```

`.+` will match everything up to the `2008` (including `(1994)`).

You need to use a non greedy match. As outlined in [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

```
+?        Match 1 or more times, not greedily
```

So try instead:

```
(.+?)(\d{4})
```

Edit: As noted in comments. Capturing `(.+)` is redundant. As is the conditional. Therefore the code looks like:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    s/(\d{4})/<y>$1<\/y>/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Ken, Robert. (1994). Lessons from Hull House for the contemporary urban university 2008. Social Service Review, 68(3), 299-321.
Robert, John. 1994. Lessons from Hull House for the contemporary urban university 2008. Social Service Review.
```

Also:

- Turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.
- beware of `open`ing a file based on user input. That's dangerous if you don't santise your input.
- 3 argument `open` is a good idea anyway.

Comment: Also important to note is that 1) You don't have to use that `if` statement, since it is built into the `s///` to only replace if it matches, 2) without an anchor, `(.+?)` will match as little as possible, in other words: 1 character, hardly worth the effort, and most importantly: 3) Capturing anything at all except the year is completely redundant.

Comment: @TLP: *"without an anchor, `(.+?)` will match as little as possible, in other words: 1 character"* Even a non-greedy pattern won't move the *start* position of the match -- that is always placed as early as possible as long as the entire pattern matches. Non-greediness affects only the *end* of the match. In this case `.+?` will match everything up to the first set of four digits and will never match just one character.

Comment: @Sobrique: It's worth pointing out that, without something more elaborate, this will modify *every* subsequence of four decimal digits. So something like `my bank account number is 76151387` would be changed to `my bank account number is <y>7615</y><y>1387</y>`. It would also be nice to change the delimiters for `s///` so that the slash doesn't need escaping.

Comment: I have tried the above coding. It generates <y> tag for all years. But can i know how to tag <y> only for the first occurrence i.e. only for <y>1994</y> and not for 2008

Comment: `s/\A\D+(\d{4})/<y>$1</y>/;` Or just omit the 'g' at the end.